# Simplification of proof for $\exists c>0$ such that $|x+y|\leq c(1+\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inequality

Question: Consider function $f(x,y)=|x+y|$ for $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $\exists c>0$ such that $|x+y|\leq c(1+\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$.

My proof:

i) if $|x|,|y|\leq 1$, then $|x+y|\leq 2\leq 2(1+\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$;

ii): if $|x|\leq 1$ and $|y|\geq 1$, then $|x+y|\leq 1+|y|\leq 1+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$;

iii): if $|x|,|y|\geq 1$ such that $|x|\geq |y|$, then $|x+y|\leq2|x|\leq2(1+\sqrt{x^2})\leq 2(1+\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$.

Hence, we conclude, and $c=2$ works for the claim.

However, I feel like there should be a ***simpler proof*** which does not prove in a case-by-case way like I did.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that

$$|x|=\sqrt{x^2}\leq\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\quad\text{and}\quad|y|=\sqrt{y^2}\leq\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

and so

$$|x+y|\leq|x|+|y|\leq 2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<2\left(1+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

$|x+y|\leq |x|+|y|\leq 2\sqrt {x^2+y^2}\leq2\sqrt {1+x^2+y^2}$

Answer (score 2):

Write $x=r\cos\phi$, $\>y= r\sin\phi$, assuming $r>0$ (the case $r=0$ is trivial). Then it is about the inequality
$$r(\cos\phi+\sin\phi)\leq c(1+r)\ ,$$
or
$$\cos\phi+\sin\phi\leq c{1+r\over r}\ .$$It is well known that here the LHS is $\leq\sqrt{2}$, and the given value is reached for $\phi={\pi\over4}$. Therefore we have to make sure that
$$c{1+r\over r}\geq\sqrt{2}$$
for all $r>0$. Now ${1+r\over r}>1$, and $\lim_{r\to\infty}{1+r\over r}=1$. It follows that the smallest $c$ for which the given inequality holds throughout is $c=\sqrt{2}$.